# Music won't play in HTML document. Ideas?

Tags: html, css

I've had this problem for a while now and I don't know what the issue could be so I just leave this part out of my websites. But for my game that's built-in my HTML document, I would love to add some back music in for the player, but for some reason, the music will not play. I've copied exactly as the tutorials on YouTube have said and showed but I don't understand why it won't work for me.

Am I missing something? I don't think I am.

...

```
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rock+Salt&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">

<iframe width="0" height="0" src= "https://www.youtuberepeater.com/watch?v=6GVgncA9oiw#gsc.tab=0></iframe>

</head>
```

...

Is it supposed to be in the header? One tutorial said to place it in the head, and they did the exact same thing and it worked out for them. Does this only work in HTML5? Or any HTML because I'm using solely HTML and it doesn't seem to work out for me.

Is there anything else that does a similar feature to what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

You're missing an end-quote at the end of your src attribute.

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" src= "https://www.youtuberepeater.com/watch?v=6GVgncA9oiw#gsc.tab=0"></iframe>
```

Use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to ensure these mistakes are caught and don't give you trouble.

Also, I don't know for certain, but I think it's against the YouTube Terms of Service to hide the video player like you're attempting to do.  In any case, I don't know how you expect the user to click play in the event that autoplay is disabled.

Comment: Surely such a mistake qualifies as a typo, which means the question should be closed, not answered, right?

Comment: @Snow There wasn't enough room in the comments for all this.  I wanted to make sure this person knew where to find a validator so that they wouldn't have to post on Stack Overflow every time they hit a minor bug.

Answer (score -2):

You are missing an end quote:

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" src="https://www.youtuberepeater.com/watch?v=6GVgncA9oiw#gsc.tab=0"></iframe>
```

but the prefeered way to do what you are trying to achieve is to use the  attribute.

```
  <audio controls autoplay>
<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
```

> Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp

Note: you will have to download the audio instead of linking to it AFAIK

Comment: Thanks, I used an MP3 and while it did work, for some reason autoplay wouldn't work on google chrome, I don't know about any other websites but google is the main website I'll be using. And it wouldn't play if I didn't add "control" to the audio tag. So if I wanted to reach what my expectations were, I had to add an audio tag with loop and control in which I'll have to manually start the music for it to in order to continue playing over and over.